# adding header files in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: c++, eclipse, header-files

I'm having trouble adding header files to my C++ projects in Eclipse Kepler. When I have Eclipse start a new project all the standard libraries are included in a separate folder hierarchy (see image) but I can't seem to figure out how to add these to existing projects.

Does anyone have a solution?
[image: includes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem here was that I wasn't specifying Linux GCC (I'm using Ubuntu) as my toolchain when I created the project through Eclipse's new project interface. When I specified this as the compiler, the project was made with all the the includes I was looking for.

Hope this helps someone else out.